# Gradle task to create docker mysql container and fill it with databases and empty tables

Tags: mysql, docker, gradle, docker-compose, liquibase

Basically the title, is there any good approaches i should look into? Currently i have an idea that gradle task will run docker compose file that creates mysql container and then something like liquibase that creates database and fills it with empty tables , but i'm having troubles finding how to make it real and if this is even possible, and maybe there are other better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to run somehow docker from gradle? I'm not using it so I'm just asking. If so, then you can probably:

- create a customized container with
  [jib-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin)
- run that container (watchout for container startup)
- execute the liquibase

`liquibase` is not ment to create database itself, it only manages the schema. So you should prepare the database before (by customized image or just by docker)

Comment: yeah, thanks. Customized image seems the best solution.